# Text literal problem in MVC3 Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Why am I required to use the `<text>` tag to enclose the pipe literal '|' in this markup?  Surely it is well outside the scope of the ActionLink method.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.DetailItem.PlannedResources)
{ 
    <tr>
        <td>
            @if (Model.ViewMode == ViewMode.Edit)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PlannedResourceId }) <text>|</text>
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = item.PlannedResourceId})                                                                     
            }
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PlannedResourceId })
        </td>
        <td>
            | @item.ResourceType.Name
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

If I don't use it, I get the error `CS1525: Invalid expression term '|'`, but the second '|' gets by unhindered.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's because when you are inside a statement with `{` and `}` only HTML tags are considered as literals, everything else is server side script. So you need to either use standard HTML tags such as `<div>`, `<span>`, ... or if you want to use a literal use the special `<text>` tag which is not outputted to the response.

Comment: Interesting, but why then does my other | char (see edits) outside the inner {}, but it's still within an outer {} for a loop.  Does being inside an HTML tag escape it somehow?

Comment: @ProfK, I don't understand. What inner and outer `{}` are you talking about? What edits?

Comment: @ProfK, sorry, now I see your edits. In the outer `{}`, the `|` character is inside a tag: `<td>`, that's why it works whereas in the inner there's no tag: you have `{`, some server side helper `@Html.ActionLink` followed directly by `|`, no tag and when there's no tag it is considered server side.

Answer (score 20):

If your text spans multiple lines you can use the `<text>` tag.
`<text>your text here...`
`over to the 2nd line.</text>`

Alternately, if you simply want to output the pipe character use the `@:` directive to specify text,
so `@:|` will output `|`, and the error message will disappear.